# How to connect a SSL MQTT client with a CA signed server certificate?

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I need to sign up for an MQTT address, but I get an exception. As far as I know, I do not need to upload any certificates, just use the server's. What should I do?

Code:

```
public void connect() throws MqttException{
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setUserName("username");
    options.setPassword("123456".toCharArray());
    options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);

    client = new MqttClient("ssl://myadress:1883", MqttClient.generateClientId());
    client.setCallback(callback);
    System.out.println(topic);
    try {
        client.connect(options);
        client.subscribe(topic);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm using the Eclipse Paho library, and I did not find (or, if I did, I did not understand) anything very enlightening in the library's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply your own `SSLSocketFactory` that has it's own `TrustManager` that knows to trust your certificate.

You add the SSLSocketFactory to the `MqttClientOptions` object that gets passed to `MqttClient.connect()` call.

There are plenty of examples online about settings up a SSLSocketFactory with your own CA certs.

Comment: Hey, hardillb. Thanks for the awnser. Do I need to have a CA cert?

Comment: You need a copy of the CA cert that was used to sign the cert the broker is using.

Comment: Got it! So I need the same certificate as my server?

Comment: You need the certificate that signed the certificate the broker (not server) is using. This may or may not be the same thing

Comment: I do not totally understand, but it's a start! thank you :)